# Update column from another table's column based on matching columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

The following query is updating all the (80k) records instead of the ones that match (5k). What is wrong with it and how can it be corrected?

```
update ALAM set ALAM.CDate = (select IDCP.CDate from IDCP 
                              where ALAM.ASID = IDCP.ASID and ALAM.AID = IDCP.AID 
                                    and ALAM.MCode = '10001')
```

Record Count of ALAM Table = 80,000 records approx
Record Count of IDCP Table = 5,000 records approx

As additional information:

```
select ALAM.ASID, ALAM.AID, ALAM.CDate 
from ALAM, IDCP 
where ALAM.ASID = IDCP.ASID and ALAM.AID = IDCP.AID and ALAM.MCode = '10001'
```

result 5000 records approx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO ALAM
   USING IDCP 
      ON ALAM.ASID = IDCP.ASID 
         AND ALAM.AID = IDCP.AID 
         AND ALAM.MCode = '10001'
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET CDate = IDCP.CDate;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify version of SQL Server. You can use the proprietary `UPDATE...FROM` syntax in all versions.

```
UPDATE ALAM
SET ALAM.CDate = IDCP.CDate
FROM ALAM
JOIN IDCP ON  ALAM.ASID = IDCP.ASID and ALAM.AID = IDCP.AID 
WHERE ALAM.MCode = '10001'
```

Or the more standard `MERGE` statement in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

In the first statement you haven't stated the WHERE clause on the main query. So it executes on all the records in ALAM (which I assume are 80K).

In the second query you join the 2 tables, so you only take the ones from ALAM that match the ones in IDCP. This is what went wrong.

```
UPDATE ALAM
SET a.CDate = i.CDate
FROM ALAM a INNER JOIN IDCP i ON a.ASID = i.ASID and a.AID = i.AID 
WHERE a.MCode = '10001'
```

Answer (score 0):

As tjekkles said you left off the WHERE clause on the update which you can pull out of the inner select:

```
update ALAM set ALAM.CDate = (select IDCP.CDate
                                from IDCP 
                               where ALAM.ASID = IDCP.ASID
                                 and ALAM.AID  = IDCP.AID ) 
 where ALAM.MCode = '10001'
```